# Do two actions with a form

Tags: forms

Hey, I'm just wondering if it's possible to have a form in html do two things on submit, have the action go to a url like normal (PayPal) but also go to a php program to send me an email.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX to submit the two actions requests individually.

Alternatively, just process the request at your server end code and make the appropriate requests from there.

There maybe better solutions depending on the exact context.